# Scan algorithm in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have encountered some problem while doing Scan algorithm (operating system) in Java. I'd done the shortest seek time first algorithm to calculate for the disk optimization:

```
private int[] arrangeBySSTF(int current, int sequence[])
{
    int n = sequence.length;
    int sstf[] = new int[n];
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++){
        sstf[i] = sequence[i];
    }

    int ii = -1;
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        ii = i;
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            int distance = Math.abs(current - sstf[j]);
            if(distance < minimum)
            {
                ii = j;
                minimum = distance;
            }
        }
        int tmp = sstf[i];
        sstf[i] = sstf[ii];
        sstf[ii] = tmp;
        current = sstf[i];
    }
    return sstf;
}
```

However, I have no idea how to kick-start for the Scan algorithm. Does anybody can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not very clear. Please show us, with sample input, output and your desired output.

Comment: It is about the algorithm to calculate for the disk optimization in operating system

Answer (score 0):

Scan algorithm works by serving the request in one direction.Here is quick and dirty code for your problem.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
private int[] arrangeBySCAN(int current, int sequence[]) {
    // Assuming inward movement i.e going toward zero
    int n = sequence.length;
    int scan[] = new int[n + 1];
    int temp[] = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp[i] = sequence[i];
    }
    temp[n] = 0;
    Arrays.sort(temp);
    // find first element in array temp which is less than current
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (temp[i] > current) {
            index = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    int k = 0;
    // Server all request upto zero move backward
    for (int i = index; i >= 0; --i, ++k) {
        scan[k] = temp[i];
    }
    // move forward from zero
    for (int i = index + 1; i < temp.length; i++, ++k) {
        scan[k] = temp[i];
    }
    return scan;
}
```

The algorithm works by first sorting the sequence and then finding a request that is less than current and serving all request until zero.After this server the remaining request by moving forward away form zero.

Several optimization can be made in above code by using only one array instead of 2 and using binary search to find the 1st element which is less than current and I expect that you can perform optimization on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is documented properly to make you understand:

```
package diskScheduling;
import java.util.*;
public class SCAN {

    public static int  callSCAN(int arr[],int init,int maxreq){
        /* In this algorithm head moves only in one direction and
         *  on reaching the boundary its reverses its direction 
         *  Here in this algorithm , we implement it move in forward direction first
         *  ,i.e towards higher track requests,then towards lower track request*/

        int sum=0,len=arr.length;

        //sorting the requests
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        //finding virtual location of init in the request array
        //binary search returns the index of search element if found 
        //else it returns -(insertion point) -1
        int pos=    Arrays.binarySearch(arr, init);

        pos=-pos-1;
//      System.out.println(pos);
        int left=pos-1,right=pos;

        //moving towards right side first in the array
        sum+=Math.abs(init-arr[right]);
        System.out.println(arr[right]);
        while(right<len-1){
            sum+=Math.abs(arr[right]-arr[right+1]);
            System.out.println(arr[right+1]);
            right++;
        }
        /* moving to maximum possible track request from
         *  where head will reverse its direction  */
        sum+=Math.abs(arr[len-1]-maxreq);
        System.out.println(maxreq);


        //now moving towards left direction .
        sum+=Math.abs(maxreq-arr[left]);
        System.out.println(arr[left]);

        while(left!=0){
            sum+=Math.abs(arr[left]-arr[left-1]);
            System.out.println( arr[left-1]);
            left--;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //maxreq maximum possible disk request
        int maxreq = 200;
        //request array
        int arr[]={98,183,37,122,14,124,65,67};
        // disk head starts at init
        int init=53;
        int res=callSCAN(arr,init,maxreq);
        System.out.println("Total Head Movement= "+res);
    }

}
```